# Is it possible to ask a question which isn't considered "off-topic" on this site?

Tags: discussion

Example #1: [Why do the large treasure chests in Super Mario Bros. 3 use larger-than-1x1 pixels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372872/why-do-the-large-treasure-chests-in-super-mario-bros-3-use-larger-than-1x1-pixe)

Example #2: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/25696/is-there-any-way-to-get-over-my-mental-block-in-regards-to-going-through-my-so

Both literally **could not be more on-topic**, and use **specific, pre-existing tags**, yet both immediately say:

> Closed. This question is **off-topic**. It is not currently accepting answers.

I'm now convinced that there is just no way to ask a question on this site which will be allowed to stay up. It just cannot be done. They are **always** closed as "off-topic" or some other random excuse which in no way applies to the actual question. Those examples are not off-topic. No human on this planet could possibly honestly think so.

Are these broken robots moderating the site or what? They cannot be humans. At least not humans with the intention of moderating the place correctly.

I'm sick and tired of wasting tons of time and energy writing questions which don't even get to stay up. It's indescribably insulting.

Isn't it bad enough that few of them ever get any readers who could possibly answer? You have to make it *impossible* to answer them by closing them with an objectively false reason?

Comment: I'm going to move this to meta, but I'll also point out this is a pattern of behaviour that is frowned upon.  *Please* use a single account in the future, otherwise you're going to keep running into issues with the system as well as with the community.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, as a matter of fact, it *is* possible to ask questions that are on-topic.

That said, questions need to meet our standards.  "Why did they design it that way?" questions, like your linked question, are explicitly off-topic.  It is **not** on-topic; in fact, there's a specific close reason to give you feedback about it.  The problem isn't that it's closed; it's that *a new account can't see the feedback*.  You have no way of seeing that.

This is a problem; you don't have to register an account, but you're going to have a very rough go if you don't even use the same account every time.  You can't help us help you without that, as new accounts are extremely restricted in their capabilities.  Those restrictions are lifted slightly for their own questions, but that requires using the same account.  See where I'm going with this?

> Are these broken robots moderating the site or what? They cannot be humans. At least not humans with the intention of moderating the place correctly.

I'm going to take exception to this.  We are **volunteers**.  We are here because we care about this site.  This kind of language violates the Code of Conduct, and will not be tolerated.  You are allowed to disagree with the closure.  You are not allowed to insult the people trying to keep the site clean.

> I'm sick and tired of wasting tons of time and energy writing questions which don't even get to stay up. It's indescribably insulting.

We've spent a ton of time and energy keeping the site clean so that people can find the answers to their problems.  It's rather insulting to have someone ignore all our standards and take offense to us doing so.  We try our best to familiarize new users with our site, but it doesn't always work.  We operate in good faith, so it's best that you do as well.

> You have to make it impossible to answer them by closing them with an objectively false reason?

That is literally *why* we close questions.  You'd do well to learn more about our site before continuing to ask questions.